# Multicolumn in array . How do I place the dividend in right place?

Tags: arrays

**Edit:** The original question before being re-edited too much:

```
\newcommand\divspace{\,}
\[   
    \arraycolsep=0em
    \begin{array}{r@{\divspace}c@{\divspace}lllll}
      & & \multicolumn{4}{l}{7.24}&          \\
    \cline{2-6}

    3427 &\big)&\multicolumn{6}{c}{24811.48}\\
      & &                   23989&  \\
    \cline{3-4}
      &   &                 8224&&  \\
      & &                   6854&&  \\
    \cline{3-4}
      & &                  13708&&  \\
    \cline{3-5}
    \end{array}
    \]
```

MWE say 300 div by 2 should give 150.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\divspace{\,} 
\[
\arraycolsep=0em
\begin{array}{r@{\divspace}c@{\divspace}lllll}
 & \multicolumn{3}{r}{150}\\
\cline{2-6}
2  &\big)&\multicolumn{3}{l}{300}&\\
  & &                   20&&&&\\
\cline{3-4}
  & &                   10&0&&&\\
  & &                   10&0&&&\\
\cline{3-5}
  & &                     &0&0&&
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: and what does this have to do with `latex3`?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code so that it forms a compilable MWE. Now, what exactly is you question?

Comment: I am trying to put the dividend just after the big ) bracket.  I don't understand the & ampersand symbol use.

Comment: @daleif , sorry its about array

Answer (score 1):

The mark up seems to complex; you want to align digits, so do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{r@{\,}cccc}
  &     & \multicolumn{3}{l}{150}\\
\cline{2-5}
2 &\big)& 3 & 0 & 0 \\
  &     & 2 & 0 &  \\
\cline{3-5}
  &     & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  &     & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\cline{3-5}
  &     &   &   & 0
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but I witnessed the very first moment of posting the question and it was re-edited too much that it became another question. So, I re-posted the original question (which exactly conforms to the title).

The incorrect placement of the dividend is shown by the code output:

[image]

To solve the problem correct the first row `\cline` to `\cline{2-7}` and second row as `\multicolumn{5}{c}{24811.48}` then make consistent number of `&`s in all rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[   
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{array}{rc*5{l}}
      &       & \multicolumn{4}{l}{7.24}&    \\    \cline{2-7}
3427\,&\big)\,&\multicolumn{5}{c}{24811.48}  \\
      &       &                   23989&&&&  \\    \cline{3-4}
      &       &                   8224&& &&  \\
      &       &                   6854&& &&  \\    \cline{3-4}
      &       &                   13708&&&&  \\    \cline{3-5}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out by @egreg, however, the markup becomes too complex, especially if we also need align the digits (10 columns at least may be needed in this case). Yet a simple markup solution (three columns) with a typographically pleasing output plus aligned digits can be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}   
\begin{array}{rcl}
       &       &  7.24                              \\    \cline{2-3}
 3427\,&\big)\,&  24811.48                          \\
       &       &  \underline{23989_{}}              \\    %\cline{3-3}
       &       &  \phantom{23}{8224}                \\
       &       &  \phantom{23}\underline{6854_{}}   \\    %\cline{3-3}
       &       &  \phantom{23}{13708}               \\    
       &       &  \phantom{23}\underline{13708_{}}  \\    %\cline{3-3}
       &       &  \phantom{231370}0                 \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\phantom{}` for alignment and replaced the `\cline`s with `\underline{}` to exactly fit the digits above. The extra `_{}` inside each `\underline{}` is to lower the line a bit for improving the visual appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a long division?  How about something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{longdiv}

\begin{document}    
\longdiv{300}{2}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: The `longdiv` package unfortunately works only with integers.